# Recursively delete elements of an array and their children by checking keys only

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, diff

I am looking for a way to recursively delete parts of an array, and these part's children, by checking only keys.

In the example below $array is the input array, and $remove contains the keys that should be removed from $array:

```
$array = [
    'key1' => [
        'key11' => [],
        'key12' => [
            'key121' => [],
            'key122' => [],
            'key123' => [],
        ],
        'key13' => [],
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'key21' => [],
        'key22' => [],
        'key23' => [],
        'key24' => [],
        'key25' => [
            'key251' => [
                'key2511' => [],
                'key2512' => [],
                'key2513' => [],
                'key2514' => [],
                'key2515' => [],
            ],
            'key252' => [
                'key2521' => [],
                'key2522' => [],
                'key2523' => [],
                'key2524' => [],
                'key2525' => [],
            ],

        ],
    ],
    'key3' => [
        'key31' => [],
        'key32' => [],
        'key33' => [],
        'key34' => [],
        'key35' => [
            'key351' => [
                'key3511' => [],
                'key3512' => [],
                'key3513' => [],
                'key3514' => [],
                'key3515' => [],

            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$remove = [
    'key1' => [
        'key12' => [
            'key121' => [],
        ],
        'key13' => [],
    ],
    'key2' => [
        'key25' => [
            'key251' => [
                'key2514' => [
                ],
            ],
            'key252' => [],
        ],
    ],
    'key3' => [],
];
```

I have written an ugly and non-recursive algorithm:

```
foreach ($array as $k1 => $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
        foreach ($v2 as $k3 => $v3) {
            foreach ($v3 as $k4 => $v4) {
                if (isset($array[$k1][$k2][$k3][$k4]) && isset($remove[$k1][$k2][$k3][$k4]) && 0 === count($remove[$k1][$k2][$k3][$k4])) {
                    unset($array[$k1][$k2][$k3][$k4]);
                }
            }
            if (isset($array[$k1][$k2][$k3]) && isset($remove[$k1][$k2][$k3]) && 0 === count($remove[$k1][$k2][$k3])) {
                unset($array[$k1][$k2][$k3]);
            }
        }
        if (isset($array[$k1][$k2]) && isset($remove[$k1][$k2]) && 0 === count($remove[$k1][$k2])) {
            unset($array[$k1][$k2]);
        }
    }
    if (isset($array[$k1]) && isset($remove[$k1]) && 0 === count($remove[$k1])) {
        unset($array[$k1]);
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

It returns the output that I am looking for:

```
array(2) {
  ["key1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["key11"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["key12"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["key122"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["key123"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
  ["key2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["key21"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["key22"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["key23"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["key24"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["key25"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["key251"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["key2511"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["key2512"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["key2513"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["key2515"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is, how can I make this functionality recursive, as in theory, $array could be nested indefinitely?

Any help would be gratefully accepted. Thank you!

---

In the meantime, I came up with an alternative solution:

```
function array_remove_key_recursive($input, $remove)
{
    $ret = [];

    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $remove)) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (count($remove[$key]) > 0) {
                    $diff_recursive = array_remove_key_recursive($value, $remove[$key]);
                    if (count($diff_recursive) > 0) {
                        $ret[$key] = $diff_recursive;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if ($value != $remove[$key]) {
                    $ret[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $ret[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: add all code, that explains your problem, to your question

Comment: Code added to question, as requested.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I would do it

```
function test (&$arr, $remove) {
    $keys =array_keys ($remove, [], true) ;
    $arr =array_filter ($arr, function ($v, $k) use ($remove, $keys) {
            return !in_array ($k, $keys, true) ; 
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH            
    ) ;
    $keys =array_diff (array_keys ($remove), $keys) ;
    foreach ( $keys as $key )
        test ($arr [$key], $remove [$key]) ;
}

test ($array, $remove) ;
print_r ($array) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it an it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function that recursively does what you need.

```
function remove_by_keys(array $array, array $remove)
{
    // Copy the input array into the result; will remove parts of it
    // according to the information stored in $remove
    $result = $array;

    // Check the keys to remove
    foreach ($remove as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === []) {
            // Remove the key and the entire value associated with the key
            unset($result[$key]);
        } else {
            // Keep the key, recursively remove parts of the value (next level)
            $result[$key] = remove_by_keys($array[$key], $remove[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**How it works:**

The function receives two parameters: `$array` is the input array, `$remove` is the list of keys (and sub-keys) to remove from `$array`.

It makes a copy of the input array then analyzes the keys (`$key`) and the values of `$remove`. If the value is `[]` (the empty array) then the corresponding key and value of `$array` are removed completely from the result. If `$remove[$key]` is not `[]` then the function is recursively called for `$array[$key]` and `$remove[$key]` (the next level) and the value it returns (the filtered `$array[$key]`) is stored in the results array at key `$key`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is elegantly simple. My favorite type of solution!